# Running a Loop into sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want a sql select query to create a table and add a column with a value that is incremented automatically :

For example:

```
Create table Core 
as 
SELECT w.id, w.core_name,CAST('MD_1' AS CHARACTER VARYING) AS INDEX 
from myTable;
```

The field INDEX will take the default value `'md_1'`

But what I want is the 1 automatically increments according to the records 
and as result i want to have something like that

```
ID|core_name|index|
 1|      xxx| MD_1
 2|      xxx| MD_2
 3|      xxx| MD_3
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `cast()` is not needed in the select. Using `'MD_1'`  will do just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't entirely clear what you are asking but if you just want to have 'md_' followed by the row number, the simplest solution is:

```
('md_' || row_number() over (rows unbounded preceding)) as "index"
```

The reason I am not entirely sure is that SQL doesn't really have the concept of an autoincrement value to a record set.  Instead what we are doing is grabbing the row number based on the current grouping and ordering of the set and appending it to a value.  This is similar but conceptually rather different since the concept can be used in a number of other cases as well (such as running totals).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was very helpful, i have another question if you may help me : 
i want to insert into my table value that incremented according to a field (name)
for exemple


Name   Value
------- |---------|
aaaa |MD_1  |
aaaa |MD_2  | 
aaaa |MD_3  | 
bbbb |MD_1  | 
bbbb |MD_2  | 
bbbb |MD_3  | 
bbbb |MD_4  |
cccc  |MD_1  | 
cccc  |MD_2  |

Comment: You can always do:
`INSERT INTO foo (cols) SELECT ...`