# Insert value into field that incremented according to a fiels value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to insert values into a field in Postgres default values that incremented according to other field?

In my table I have already the field `name` and I want to insert the values of the field 'index' like that:

```
Name | Value 
aaaa |MD_1 | 
aaaa |MD_2 | 
aaaa |MD_3 | 
bbbb |MD_1 | 
bbbb |MD_2 | 
bbbb |MD_3 | 
bbbb |MD_4 | 
cccc |MD_1 | 
cccc |MD_2 |
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as your last question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745036/running-a-loop-into-sql-query

Comment: @Hchliyah: Do you mean to say that your table already has `name` and `value` is null right now, and you want to update them as you mentioned in the question??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are saying that that you want to update the value field like the example above. Unfortunately you cannot use `row_number over partition by` in the update statement, but you can use it in `select`.

What you can do is

1. create another temporary table and populate `value` field in it.
2. truncate your main table
3. copy data from temporary table to your main
   table.

Say your main table is table1. Then do this

<kbd>**[**`SQLFiddle Demo`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5f0cb/1)**</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE Table2 (Name varchar(4), val varchar(6));

INSERT INTO TABLE2 
SELECT NAME,('MD_'||row_number() over (partition by name order by name)) FROM TABLE1;

truncate table table1;

insert into table1 
select name,val from table2;
```

Comment: Thank you @Utsav it was very helpful!